# Acumular saldo en una cuenta padre de cuentas hijas con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tabla cuentas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo unico que he conseguido es:

```
UPDATE cuentas as cuentas_A 
JOIN (SELECT cta, SUM(saldo) AS suma_saldo FROM cuentas WHERE nivel = 3 GROUP BY cta) AS cuentas_B 
 ON cuentas_B.cta = cuentas_A.cta
SET cuentas_A.saldo = cuentas_B.suma_saldo
WHERE cuentas_A.nivel = 1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se me complica es que hay cuentas contables que tienen 3 niveles y otras solo tienen 2 niveles.
Las que tienen 3 niveles acumularan saldo en el nivel 2 y en el nivel 3.
Las que solo tienen 2 niveles, acumularan saldo solamente en el nivel 1.

Ayuda!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a tomarme del mismo código de [David JP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/119615/david-jp)

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  cuenta int,
  subcuenta int,
  subsubcuenta int,
  nivel int,
  saldo float
  );
INSERT INTO cuentas (cuenta, subcuenta, subsubcuenta, nivel, saldo) VALUES
  (102,0,0,1,null),
  (102,1,0,2,null),
  (102,1,1,3,600),
  (102,1,2,3,200),
  (102,2,0,2,null),
  (102,2,1,3,500),
  (102,2,2,3,100),
  (103,0,0,1,null),
  (103,1,0,2,3),
  (103,2,0,2,7);
```

**Yo creo que no debes actualizar la data** (máxime si es contable). Los datos originales son los mismos sin importar de la presentación de la información. En otro caso ¿Vas a correr un update cada vez que se registre un dato nuevo?

El contenido de la tabla cuentas es

| cuenta | subcuenta | subsubcuenta | nivel | saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 0 | 0 | 1 | null |
| 102 | 1 | 0 | 2 | null |
| 102 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 600 |
| 102 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 200 |
| 102 | 2 | 0 | 2 | null |
| 102 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 102 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 103 | 0 | 0 | 1 | null |
| 103 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 103 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 7 |

**Alternativa A**

Si tú corres una query usando window functions para agregar totales y subtotales

```
select cuenta,
       subcuenta,
       subsubcuenta,
       nivel,
       case nivel
           when 1 then sum(saldo) over (partition by cuenta)
           when 2 then sum(saldo) over (partition by cuenta, subcuenta)
           else saldo end as saldo
from cuentas
```

Obtendrás

| cuenta | subcuenta | subsubcuenta | nivel | saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1400 |
| 102 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 800 |
| 102 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 600 |
| 102 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 200 |
| 102 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 600 |
| 102 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 102 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 103 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 10 |
| 103 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 103 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 7 |

Que es lo que pedías en un comienzo.

**Alternativa B**

Si tu tabla de datos original sólo contuviese los saldos y no los totales ni subtotales

| cuenta | subcuenta | subsubcuenta | nivel | saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 600 |
| 102 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 200 |
| 102 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 500 |
| 102 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 103 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 103 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 7 |

Podrías obtener aquellos (los totales y subtotales) con una query como:

```
SELECT *
FROM cuentas

UNION ALL 

SELECT cuenta,
       0          as subcuenta,
       0          as subsubcuenta,
       1          as nivel,
       SUM(saldo) as saldo
FROM cuentas
GROUP BY cuenta

UNION ALL 

SELECT cuenta,
       subcuenta,
       0          as subsubcuenta,
       1          as nivel,
       SUM(saldo) as saldo
FROM cuentas
GROUP BY cuenta, subcuenta
```

La cual arroja la misma salida que mostré en la Alternativa A.

---

En ambas soluciones, si le insertas una nueva fila con saldo a la tabla original la consulta A o B mostrarán los nuevos subtotales sin necesidad de alterar los datos.

Me gusta más la alternativa B porque los totales y subtotales no son contablemente un movimiento, claramente se insertaron a mano para efectos de formatear el reporte, y eso es poco mantenible.

Comment: En realidad esta tabla debe llamarse "saldos_contables" y las cuentas hijas se nutren a base de puro triggers de otra tabla llamada "cuentas_contables_hijas". Asi funcionan la mayoria de sistemas contables, supongo que la tabla de saldos contables es para agilizar las consultas sql.

Comment: hmmm no creo que sea tan generalizado el uso de triggers para eso, mal que mal es lógica de negocios, debiera estar en el código más que en la BBDD, pero no es ni de lejos mi área de experticia

Comment: @Jorch: *"Asi funcionan la mayoria de los sistemas contables"*. ? En los sistemas grandes no, los disparadores en sistemas transaccionales pueden provocar efectos indeseables. Recomendable leer sobre [*OLAP*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP).

Answer (score 2):

Casi lo tenías, te ha faltado combinar por dos campos y, paradójicamente, empezar por el final:

```
UPDATE cuentas JOIN (
    SELECT cta,scta,0 sscta,SUM(saldo) total
      FROM cuentas
      WHERE nivel=3
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 USING(cta,scta,sscta)
  set saldo=total;
UPDATE cuentas JOIN (
    SELECT cta,0 scta,SUM(saldo) total
      FROM cuentas
      WHERE nivel=2
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 USING(cta,scta)
  set saldo=total;
```

Ejecutando estas dos queries en este mismo orden obtendrás:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| cta  | scta | sscta | nivel | saldo |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  102 |    0 |     0 |     1 |  1400 |
|  102 |    1 |     0 |     2 |   800 |
|  102 |    1 |     1 |     3 |   600 |
|  102 |    1 |     2 |     3 |   200 |
|  102 |    2 |     0 |     2 |   600 |
|  102 |    2 |     1 |     3 |   500 |
|  102 |    2 |     2 |     3 |   100 |
|  103 |    0 |     0 |     1 |    10 |
|  103 |    1 |     0 |     2 |     3 |
|  103 |    2 |     0 |     2 |     7 |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

A partir del dataset que propones:

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  cta int,
  scta int,
  sscta int,
  nivel int,
  saldo float
  );
INSERT INTO cuentas (cta, scta, sscta, nivel, saldo) VALUES
  (102,0,0,1,null),
  (102,1,0,2,null),
  (102,1,1,3,600),
  (102,1,2,3,200),
  (102,2,0,2,null),
  (102,2,1,3,500),
  (102,2,2,3,100),
  (103,0,0,1,null),
  (103,1,0,2,3),
  (103,2,0,2,7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si son pocos niveles fijos, lo consigues fácilmente con una consulta escalar:

```
SELECT cta, scta, sscta, nivel
     , ( SELECT sum(c2.saldo)
           FROM cuentas c2
           WHERE c2.cta = c.cta
             AND c2.scta = if(c.scta='000', c2.scta, c.scta)
             AND c2.sscta = if(c.sscta='000', c2.sscta, c.sscta)
       ) saldo
  FROM cuentas c
```

El truco es el predicado (filtrado): si el segmento de cuenta es `000` la condición es indistinta, es decir, debe sumarlo si cumple con el(los) segmento(s) anterior(es), de lo contrario la condición es que sea del mismo segmento.

Comment: No entiendo por qué se valida una respuesta que hace algo diferente a lo que el OP solicita. En la pregunta, por lo que fuera, se requirió un UPDATE de ciertas filas. Esta respuesta, aunque calcula correctamente el resultado, continúa dejando en blanco el saldo de las cuentas de acumulados. Propongo que se formule una nueva pregunta acorde a esta respuesta, o al menos que se explique por qué se prefiere esta solución: ahorrarse los disparadores, se prevén muchas más escrituras que lecturas, etc.